# Triggering 'chosen:updated' on Django Admin popup close

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-admin, jquery-chosen

I'm using the Django Admin portal as my primary methodology for toying with models in the database for my application and I prefer using the [Chosen Select plugin](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to represent the select elements on the page.  By default, the Django Admin pages are configured to trigger select elements to update their options if you modify them via the `change-related`, `add-related`, or `delete-related` buttons next to the appropriate fields.  However, this doesn't seem to trigger the `change` event for the select element...

I have the following code in a custom JavaScript file tied to the admin pages:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    options = {
        no_results_text: "Entity not found...",
        placeholder_text_multiple: "Choose entities...",
        search_contains: true
    }
    $('select').chosen(options).change(function () {
        $(this).trigger('chosen:updated');
    });
});
```

I know that this code does its job because the use of `$('#select').change()` in the browser's console will update the Chosen Select element accordingly, but this event isn't fired when the Admin popup window is closed and the select element's value is changed...

In short, I need to know what what event is triggered when the select element's options are changed so I can update the Chosen Select box as well.  I *could* in theory have an event fire when the button that's clicked to open the popup window gets focus again (after the popup is closed), but that seems clunky and I'd prefer not to do that...

Comment: Can you try this? https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/2198

Comment: As I mentioned, the `trigger('chosen:updated')` part of the code has been tested to work just fine, so it's not an issue with the trigger failing.  Unless you're asking if I can issue a `setInterval` to intermittently update the element...in which case I desperately do not want to have to do that either.